# Disable spring application metrics

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

My spring boot application pushes `spring_data_repository_invocations_percentile` metrics automatically. The application has grown very big over time and has lots of repository classes and this is causing issues with the Prometheus DB. Is there a way I can disable specific metrics like `spring_data_repository_invocations_percentile` or `http_client_requests_percentile` itself?

**Sample metrics being pushed:**

```
ad_manager_api_spring_data_repository_invocations_percentile{BusinessUnit="ads", Project="ads", TechTeam="ads", application="ad-manager-api", businessunit="ads", environment="staging", exception="None", exported_application="ad-manager-api", exported_environment="staging", instance="103.18.2.19:9273", job="ads-nodes-mumbai", method="findAllAppEvents", metric_type="gauge", phi="0.95", repository="MoEventRepository", state="SUCCESS", statistic="value", techteam="ads"}
```